# Is there any different between these two dealloc method?

Tags: objective-c, object

First one:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [AboutButton release];
}
```

Second one:

```
- (void)dealloc { 
    [AboutButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Both methods are delloc, first run the super first, the other run it later, which one is correct or there is no diff between two. thz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference, in that you are guaranteed the existence of ivars in the super class prior to the call to `[super dealloc]`. After that call, the ivars will be gone.

I don't know if calling `[super dealloc]` first will create a problem, but the [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/dealloc) for `NSObject` says you should free your memory first, and then call `[super dealloc]`

> After performing the class-specific deallocation, the subclass method should incorporate superclass versions of dealloc through a message to super

Comment: Calling [super dealloc] first won't always cause a problem, but it won't always work either.